# Estudio estadístico con R para variables no continuas ni homogéneas

Tags: r, rstudio

Me encuentro realizando el estudio estadístico de mi tesis de grado y tengo problemas para realizar un ANOVA dado que las variables no son continuas ni homogéneas. Se trata de un experimento en invernáculo para probar los efectos del uso de gel poliacrilato en cultivos, donde se simularon tipos de suelos basándose en diferentes composiciones de arcilla, arena y materia orgánica. Para cada composición de suelos determinada se realizaron dos testigos y tres repeticiones que contenían la misma dosis de gel.

Utilizo R como programa estadístico. He probado diferentes formas de análisis como dividir los datos en grupos dependiendo el porcentaje de MO para poder analizarlos, usé algunos métodos paramétricos como por ejemplo Kurskal pero no son una buena solución para el problema.

La consulta es si existe otra forma de poder realizar el análisis estadístico con R para variables no continuas ni homogéneas.

Paso a pegar una imagen de las tablas de datos que tengo para que se hagan una idea de como es el diseño. Los valores para arcilla y arena van de 0 a 100%, mientras que la MO va de 0 a 10%.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier sugerencia o comentario es bienvenido. Háganme saber si la pregunta no es clara o tiene algún error en su formulación.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Ignacio, creo que tendrías más éxito si pudieras acotar la pregunta sobre todo con un ejemplo que sea reproducible por la comunidad y explicando mejor que es lo que esperas obtener y que es lo que obtienes. Suerte.

Comment: Patricio, cómo estás? Lo que espero es poder realizar un análisis de varianza de los datos obtenidos utilizando R. Podría acotar la pregunta eliminando los scripts pero creo que son útiles para visualizar el problema. También podría copiar la tabla de datos obtenidos pero tengo entendido que a la comunidad no le sienta bien cuando se consulta al estilo "háganlo para mí, gracias". Muchas gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: @Ignacio Es complicado ayudarte con una pregunta como la que haces.

Comment: Gracias Henry. He reformulado la pregunta. Quizás ahora se entienda mejor la consulta. Saludos